# using single assert_equals statement in a Ruby Program

Tags: ruby, testing, assert

I am reading through "Metaprogramming Ruby 2: Program Like the Ruby Pros" and am a bit puzzled.

Often, the exercise files will have require_relative '../test/assertions' statement at the end of them and then one or two lines of assert_equals statements like so

```
require_relative '../test/assertions'
assert_equals 6, obj.send(:my_method, 3)
```

To be clear, these are testing code that is just a few lines up in the same file. I have set up many minitests, but never something quite so succinct! I get a load error when I try to run the file. I tried adding empty test and assertion folders, but unsurprisingly I still get a load error:

> dynamic_call.rb:20:in `require_relative': cannot load such file --

What do i need to do to be able to use these assert_equals tests?

Comment: is there an `assertions.rb` file which is in a directory called `test`, which is one directory up from the file you are running?

Comment: @UriAgassi No. "these are testing code that is just a few lines up in the same file".

Comment: @sawa - it might refer to utility code he wants to use in his tests...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `require_relative` method for loading the code to be tested. That's it. No need of such line.

Comment: Tried that as well. Then it doesn't recognize the assert_equals method (or assert_equal):
dynamic_call.rb:20:in `<main>': undefined method `assert_equals' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Is there a gem I'm missing perhaps?

Comment: I didn't mean not to include the testing framework. You have to include that.

Comment: Gotcha. Added `require 'test/unit'
extend Test::Unit::Assertions` and it runs. My testing has been fairly formulaic thus far, obviously I need to work a bit on my overall understanding!